# Can powershell extract a .tgz file?

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm brand new to powershell, and I'm trying to write a script to extract a .tar.gz file.

It requires 2 steps to unzip the file.

```
# Create a .tar file
7z.exe a -ttar files.tar *.txt 
7z.exe a -tgzip files.tar.gz files.tar


# These 2 work
 & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' e .\files.tar.gz 
 & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' x -aoa -ttar .\files.tar  -o'c:\foobar'
```

I'm trying to combine these two commands into one command so that I can skip writing the `files.tar` file to disk.

However, when I try and combine the functions, I get the error message 'incorrect function'

Is there a way to combine these 2 7zip commands into 1?

```
 & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' e .\files.tar.gz -so | & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' x -aoa -ttar -si -o'c:\foobar'
```

Comment: There's a powershell module using the 7-zip dll that might be useful here (I haven't used it at all though). Does each of those commands work correctly on their own? (If you capture the standard output from the first command in a variable and pipe it to the second command via standard input?)

Comment: Don't forget that you can use .NET assemblies fairly easily in PowerShell. You might be able to use something like SharpCompress or tar-cs.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see 7-Zip is not very good at this. People have been [asking for](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5eb1b8d5)
tarball atomic operation since 2009. [Here is a small program](https://socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-untar-or-extract-tar-ball-archive-example)
(490 KB) in Go that can do it, I [compiled it](http://bitbucket.org/svnpenn/a/downloads/go-untar.exe) for you.

```golang
package main
import (
  "archive/tar"
  "compress/gzip"
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "os"
  "strings"
 )

func main() {
  flag.Parse() // get the arguments from command line
  sourcefile := flag.Arg(0)
  if sourcefile == "" {
    fmt.Println("Usage : go-untar sourcefile.tar.gz")
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  file, err := os.Open(sourcefile)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  defer file.Close()
  var fileReader io.ReadCloser = file
  // just in case we are reading a tar.gz file,
  // add a filter to handle gzipped file
  if strings.HasSuffix(sourcefile, ".gz") {
    if fileReader, err = gzip.NewReader(file); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer fileReader.Close()
  }
  tarBallReader := tar.NewReader(fileReader)
  // Extracting tarred files
  for {
    header, err := tarBallReader.Next()
    if err != nil {
      if err == io.EOF {
        break
      }
      fmt.Println(err)
      os.Exit(1)
    }
    // get the individual filename and extract to the current directory
    filename := header.Name
    switch header.Typeflag {
    case tar.TypeDir:
      // handle directory
      fmt.Println("Creating directory :", filename)
      // or use 0755 if you prefer
      err = os.MkdirAll(filename, os.FileMode(header.Mode))
      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
      }
    case tar.TypeReg:
      // handle normal file
      fmt.Println("Untarring :", filename)
      writer, err := os.Create(filename)
      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
      }
      io.Copy(writer, tarBallReader)
      err = os.Chmod(filename, os.FileMode(header.Mode))
      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
      }
      writer.Close()
    default:
      fmt.Printf("Unable to untar type : %c in file %s", header.Typeflag,
      filename)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have python installed you can find this code handy:

```
$path = 'C:\yourPythonFile.py'
$str = "import tarfile",
       "tar = tarfile.open(""C:/yourTarFile.tar"")",
       "tar.extractall(""."")",
       "tar.close()"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($path, $str)
cd C:\
python yourPythonFile.py
```